# PSPICE graphs work separately for subcircuits, wrong when combined?

Tags: zener, error, pspice, cadence, graph

I'm working on a pulse generation circuit that will be used to drive an ultrasonic transducer. The following circuit is giving an unexpected output.

[image]

It might look complicated, but really it can be divided up into smaller parts. Also, despite the wierd names for the GNDs, they are all 0/CAPSYMs. The P-type MOSFET is the pspice model SiHFU9214 provided by Vishay.

1st Part on Right: 220V DC Power Source
[image]

Verified Output at 220V DC:
[image]

2nd Part: Pulse Controller (100ns pulse at 800sps/1250us)
[image]

The Vpulse does have a 40ns PW parameter, but that is simply due to the delays of the rest of the gates.

Verified Output of 100ns pulses at the desired frequency:
[image]

Of course, the problems always arise when trying to combine different subcircuits. The probed node (1st pic) should be reading around 220V, instead I simply get this sloped line when running the simulation for 3750us.

[image]

When running the simulation for 0.200s, it gets even better.
[image]

In my understanding, this entire node should slowly be raised to 220V when the pulse signal is not activated.
[image]

But that doesn't seem to be happening. Measuring from these next nodes for current and voltage I get a little bit of information.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm wondering if the 60Hz frequency of the DC source, and my pulse frequency of 800Hz might be causing the 10nF capacitor to not charge correctly.

Comment: The simulator is confused with many GNDs!  Is load 50 OHM resistor? The amplitude of the power line is not 170, it is  \$220\sqrt{2}\$. Why you don't try on N-channel mosfet? Gate drive for P-channel is better than your circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys. I know you were all sitting on the edge of your seats waiting for a solution to my problem, but I was eventually able to figure it out solely through the power of trial and error.

IT WAS THE TRANSFORMER! I changed it to two coupled inductors like so:

[image]

And this was the result!

[image]

Oh yes... that sexy sinusoid at the top of my pulses gets me...

Anyways, I gotta go take care of some business guys. Thanks for those of you that attempted to solve it!

( ͡ᵔ ͜ʖ ͡ᵔ )